# Не могу адаптировать данную верстку для всех типов устройств

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть следующая верстка, не получается её адаптировать для устройств шириной экрана от 1024px до 400px. Пытался при помощи bootstrap классов сделать, чтобы блоки были на всю ширину при просмотре с планшетов/телефонов, но bootstrap тянет за собой свойство `float` и это ломает верстку. Сейчас эта верстка выглядит нормально только при полноэкранном просмотре

```css
.center-div,
.center-div>* {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<center style="
    display:inline-block;
    column-width: 323px;
    column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 2;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 305px;
    " class="center-div center-mobile center-table">
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/767/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitypeople.jpg" class="center-nav-a" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;/* margin: 5px; */margin-right: -17px;width: 370px;margin-top: 10px;" width="323">
    <span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;
     bottom: -0.3em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Люди</span>
  </a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/777/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityplace.jpg" class="center-nav-a" style="position: relative;/* margin: 5px; */margin-right: 0px;width:  370px;margin-right: -17px;margin-top: 10px;" width="323">
    <span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;    bottom: -1.6em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Места</span>
  </a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/743/" target="_blank" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityfood.jpg" class="center-nav-a" style="position: relative;/* margin: 5px; */width:  100%;max-width: 370px;margin-right: -22px;margin-top: 10px;" width="323">
    <span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.8em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Еда</span>
  </a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/778/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytrack.jpg" class="center-nav-a" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;width: 370px;margin-right: -17px;margin-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;margin-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 0px;"
      width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;    bottom: -0.3em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Тропы</span></a><br>
</center>
<p>
  <a href="https://t.me/MagadanMediaChat" target="_blank"><img title="Город в Телеграм" src="/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytg.jpg" alt="" width="800" style="width: 102%;padding-left: 3px;" height=""></a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать медиазапросы

Стили для промежутка от 1024px до 400px выглядит так:

```
@media (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:400px) {
 /* Стили */
}
```

Для всех разрешений до 1024px:

```
@media (max-width:1024px) {
 /* Стили */
}
```

И, соответственно, для всех разрешений после 400px:

```
@media (min-width:400px) {
 /* Стили */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не могли бы вы подсказать, что можно предпринять чтобы эта верстка выглядела нормально для мозилы? Префиксы не помогают(